# How do you delete all lines that contain no letters from the alphabet using either grep, sed, or awk?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, text-processing

Remove all lines that don't contain a letter from the alphabet (upper or lower case)

Input :

```
34
76
0hjjAby68xp
H5e
895
```

Output :

```
0hjjAby68xp
H5e
```

Comment: Provide some code which you tired

Comment: This is pretty basic. What have you tried? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: And some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: Take a look at grep. I think it would be easier.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Start trying to think about your problems in positive rather than negative terms. In that way you'll simplify your requirements and avoid the dreaded double negative. For example `delete all lines that don't contain a letter` should be thought of as `print all lines that contain a letter` - much clearer and far less likely to lead to a convoluted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep '[[:alpha:]]' file
```

or GNU sed:

```
sed '/[[:alpha:]]/!d' file
```

Output:

```
0hjjAby68xp
H5e
```

Comment: Also `sed -n '/[[:alpha:]]/p'`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/[[:alpha:]]/' file
0hjjAby68xp
H5e
```